# Expressing a "must exist" relationship in XML schema

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, schema

I have an XML document (minimum reproducible example) that looks like this:

```
<root start="baz">
    <child name="foo">...</child>
    <child name="bar">...</child>
    <child name="baz">...</child>
</root>
```

I would like my schema to enforce the fact that the `start` attribute on the root element must reference an existing `child` node with that name. If there is no child node with a `name` attribute with that value, validation should fail. In other words the above should validate, but this should **not**:

```
<root start="baz">
    <child name="foo">...</child>
    <child name="bar">...</child>
</root>
```

What is a good way to do this? Do I really need to use an `assert` with a suitable XPath expression or is there a more natural way to express this in XSD? Thanks.

PS: assume `start` is a required attribute and the child `name` attributes are marked unique in the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `xsd:key`/`xsd:keyref`. See:

> [XML Schema key/keyref - how to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491983/xml-schema-key-keyref-how-to-use-them)

Probably somethig like:

```
<xsd:key name="root-child-name"> 
  <xsd:selector xpath="root/child"/> 
  <xsd:field xpath="@name"/> 
</xsd:key> 
<xsd:keyref name="root-start" refer="root-child-name"> 
  <xsd:selector xpath="root"/> 
  <xsd:field xpath="@start"/> 
</xsd:keyref>
```

Comment: I had to put `xpath="."` in the keyref for this to work for me, how would I do it otherwise? If `root` is in fact the root element I can't put the keyref any higher up in the document tree, so the xpath can't work, and apparently slashes aren't supported in the selector.